# MacBook Air gets added to Watchguard XTM-21W Appliance's Blocked Site List?

Tags: macos, networking, denial-of-service

We have this issue where one of our MacBook Air (Mountain Lion) users is periodically getting added to the Blocked Sites list within our [Watchguard XTM-21 Appliance (XTM21-W)](http://www.watchguard.com/products/xtm-2/compare.asp?p1=xtm21&p2=xtm22&p3=xtm23). Couple of questions:

- Is there something new in Mountain Lion that I can disable and/or dial down so that it doesn't get blocked?
- What can I do on the Watchguard side to mitigate this problem, besides adding the MacBook to the exclude list?

The only information I have with regard to our error is that the MacBook Air showed up on the block list for an IP Scanning Attack.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [knowledgebase article](https://na10.salesforce.com/articles/Article/2920?popup=true) on the Watchguard site, but you need to be logged in to get to it, so I quote:

> Question
>
> Why are internal IP addresses blocked by Default Threat Protection?
>
> Answer
>
> In Fireware XTM v11.x, when the Block Port Space Probes and Block
>   Address Space Probes check boxes are selected in the Default Packet
>   Handling configuration, all incoming traffic on all interfaces is
>   examined by the Firebox or XTM device.
>
> Some internal computers, usually DNS or email servers, could be 
>   unexpectedly blocked due to IP scan, or port scan protection.
>
> There are two options to protect against this. One option is to add
>   those servers to the Blocked Site Exceptions list.
>
> Another option is to increase the thresholds for port or address
>   space probes. For more information, in "Setup > Default Threat
>   Protection > Default Packet Handling".

I think you should check the computer to make sure it doesn't have any malicious software on it; I don't remember seeing anything to do with Macs triggering blocked sites, specifically.

Comment: Thanks. I did see this article before and did perform a scan on the system but it came up as fine.